# Overwrite a module type definition

Tags: python, python-requests

Say I was using a 3rd party API that used the requests module. Like:

```
import requests

class ThirdPartyAPI(object):
    '''
    A pretend API
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self._session = requests.Session()
```

And I wanted said API to use the `FuturesSession` form the  [requets-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) module with out editing the API source code

Would I have to subclass `ThirdPartyAPI` like so?

```
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

class SubAPI(ThirdPartyAPI):
    '''
    Dependency inject a FuturesRequets session
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._session = FuturesSession()
```

This doesn't seem to be the best way. As in the above example `_session` gets written to twice even though I only want the object that is assigned the second time.

How is this normally dealt with? Or the best way to do it?

P.S: I'm aware this is just the tip of the ice-berg for implementing async-requsts into a third party API. As all responses would then become future objects. (one step at a tine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the best way to do it from a performance point of view, since you create an unnecessary object.  But given the constraint of not modifying the base object, it is the only *possible* way.  You can't use "ThirdPartyAPI" without calling its constructor.

It's not uncommon in large OO libraries to do this sort of thing: PyQt does it in many cases, by replacing one component with another in a complex class to get some customized behavior.

Comment: Ok, Awesome. Thanks, I needed to bounce that off someone to check if it was a legit way.